# Forcing a node to stay on top when creating a cycle

Tags: graphviz, digraphs, graph-drawing

I have the following graph:

```
digraph G {
  u1, u2,  u3, u5 [ shape = oval, style=filled, fillcolor="palegreen"];

  u3 -> v3 -> v5_0 -> v5_1 -> v1;
  u5 -> v8 -> v5_1;
  v1 -> v5_2 -> v2; 
  u1 -> v2;
  v2 -> u2;
}
```

[image]

Now, I want `u2` and `u3` to be the same node, in the sense that I want the last vertex on the bottom to have an edge go up to u3 at the top of the rendered graph. But if I render:

```
digraph G {
  u1, u2,  u3, u5 [ shape = oval, style=filled, fillcolor="palegreen"];

  u3 -> v3 -> v5_0 -> v5_1 -> v1;
  u5 -> v8 -> v5_1;
  v1 -> v5_2 -> v2; 
  u1 -> v2;
  v2 -> u3;
}
```

[image]

The `u3` node ends up in the middle of the graph. How do I force `u3` to be at the top? I tried using `rank=min` on it, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

2 possible solutions:

1. use **constraint=false** on the "offending" edge (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/constraint/)

   u2 -> u3   [constraint=false]
   this produces a correct, but very ugly, edge:
   [image]
2. use **dir=back** to *reverse* the "offending" edge
   `u3 -> u2 [dir=back]`
   Giving:
   [image]